# change output directory of quarkus-openapi-generator

Tags: quarkus, openapi-generator

we generate a java rest client with the quarkus-openapi-generator maven plugin. The default output directory is target/generated-sources/open-api-json/ but i want to have it in src/main/java/...

I just added the necessary maven dependency but the part where you define the goal was already there. It came with basic quarkus setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLvok.png)

This is resonsible for all code generation. Not only the rest client. So I don't think i can just  customize it.

With the default openapi maven generator plugin you can define the output like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eacsr.png)

Any hint how to set the output dir by application.properties or in the maven plugin?
Thank you!

Was looking for application.properties option at https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-openapi-generator/dev/index.html but couldn't find one

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#configuration-reference (quarkus.smallrye-openapi.store-schema-directory)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci what you mentioned is for Server side generation of swagger files. I ask for client side generation of source file generation